# Pronunciation of  "accept"

Tags: grammar, pronunciation

When I hear people say *I accept* especially in the U.S., it sounds like they are saying "I except". What is the correct pronunciation?

Comment: Careful speakers always make the distinction: **accept** [ak-sept] -- **except** [ik-sept]. see, dictionary.reference.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Accept* and *Except* are homonyms in many British and American accents.

I myself would have to use considerable effort to try to make them sound different -- and I speak in a very neutral British accent.

This explains why they are so often confused in written English.

Comment: Accents do vary widely in pronunciation. What would be the 'correct' pronunciation, or the pronunciation in a very neutral British accent?

Comment: According to Dictionary.com: accept /ækˈsɛpt/, except /ɪkˈsɛpt/

Comment: I think you'd have a tough time finding an example of a native speaker *really* pronouncing the 'a' of 'accept' such that it's the same as the 'a' in 'cat' - which is what 'æ' is in IPA.

Comment: It was my point all long that there is indeed such thing as the IPA to answer the OP's question for *the* correct pronunciation.

Comment: "*the* correct pronunciation" isn't terribly interesting, if nobody is using it.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, the pronunciation would be "Ack-Sept" but the first vowel sound gets mangled in various ways across the country.